# Localhost and 403 Forbidden

Tags: firefox, server, windows-7, localhost, windows-7-x64

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit and Mozilla Firefox. Today I was going to buy products from one webshop. After when I told my credit card details on a secured SSL page, I always got an error message "403 Forbidden". In other words, I was forwarded to URL which started with http://localhost:44117/... The webshop owner said that the error was because of my computer, but how is that possible? I have not modified the hosts file of Windows 7.

Comment: what is the webshop url?

Comment: Sorry, I do not want to tell that, because this is not my own webshop. I was just wondering if this is happening because of my computer.

Comment: check the hostfile if you have any mappings in it

Comment: I do not have any mappings in Windows' hosts file.

Comment: do you have a admin panel for webshop?

Comment: As said, this is not my own webshop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145765/discussion-between-xms-and-divine).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar address in server log, in Referer field, after a Paytrail transaction.

It's *possibly* related to a version of F-Secure Internet Security. See https://twitter.com/vjom/status/491171682829475840 and https://forums.oscommerce.com/topic/409385-osc-234-something-wrong-on-standard-web-design-on-osc-demo-page-too/?do=findComment&comment=1743055

I don't seem to find any definitive information, though.